# For loop not executed

Tags: java, android

I am facing a problem as my for loop is not executed.
Here is my code:

```
public void sendSMS(){

    for(int t = 1; t == 5; t = t+1) {
        pp();   
    }
}

public void pp() {


    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

     phoneNo = "01234567890";
     message ="Sample msg from app";
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "testing done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "dummy Message dumped!", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

Please help.
Madiya

Comment: Your condition doesn't pass. `t = 1` on the first iteration, it doesn't `== 5`

Comment: probably you meant `t<=5`

Comment: Why did you think that would work? 1 will never `==` 5 so it will never incremement

Comment: @RUJordan obviously he thought that `for` was more like an `until` than a `while`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are going for exactly but this is your problem in your loop

```
t == 5
```

it should be something like

```
for(int t = 1; t <= 5; t = t+1) {
```

`t` is never 5 here so it will never iterate. Also, you can simplify the last part so it looks like

```
for(int t = 1; t <= 5; t++) {
```

If you look at the [Java docs for a `for loop`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fjava%2Fnutsandbolts%2Ffor.html&ei=8oFNUsCQC-33igKMw4GQCg&usg=AFQjCNE_qh1sHMkVF4oMMGrd-odVJ0P1-w&sig2=SY5uJjonu7XvkXxp4nA6vA&bvm=bv.53537100,d.cGE)

> for (initialization; termination;
>        increment) {
>       statement(s)
>   }

Now look what it says for the termination expression

> When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.

The termination expression is `false` from the beginning meaning it won't run.

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't iterate. The condition: `t == 5` just messes the whole iteration up. It should be something like either `t <= 5` or `t < 5`.

Comment: The last two won't work with the way the initialization of `t` is now.

Comment: True. Oversight on my part. Hope the other two worked though.

Comment: They would...I was just pointing that out in case you wanted to edit.

Answer (score 1):

The structure for a for loop is for `(initialization, condition, afterthought)`. You have initialized the variable to equal 1 : `t=1`
the condition parameter states when the for loop will run and since `t=1`, it does not satisfy the `t==5` condition thus it does not run.

to get your for loop to iterate five times, you would do `t <= 5`

Answer (score 0):

The for loop has three things that you need to be concerned with:

1. Initialization
2. Condition
3. Changing the value of the variable (Increment, Decrement, Multiply...)

In your for loop:

```
for(int t = 1; t == 5; t = t+1) {
    pp();   
}
```

you've rightly declared and initialized an integer variable `t`. Also, the increment statement may be true according to your requirement. The problem lies with the condition. You've specified that your `for` loop should run while `t` is equal to 5. But initially, you've set `t` to `1`. So, the control, after checking if t is equals to 5, does not enter the code within the `for` loop. That's why it isn't executing.

The solution might be:

```
for(int t = 1; t <= 5; t = t+1) {
    pp();
}
```